# Escape comma in Salesforce Data Import Wizard

Tags: data, data-import, data-import-wizard

I am trying to import a .csv file that contains commas in the data.

I tried to import it using Data Import Wizard using a tab as a separator but the Data Import Wizard doesn't detect the sublime text tab.

Is there a way to escape the comma when using comma as a separator?

Comment: There is no way to escape a coma.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I know you can't "escape" a comma, but if you wrap the field in double quotes as per the rfc this should solve the problem.

Comment: @JesseMilburn OP wrote coma, not comma. I edited the post for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Fields with embedded commas must be delimited with double-quote characters. From [documentation](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt#page-2)

the problem is that there is no unique standard for csv format. So the only option to read comma is to enclose it with double-quote

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes.